# Custom login form Yii2 Basic

Tags: authentication, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I try to make custom login form in Yii2 Basic , without the ActiveForm widget . I made form which I want to use for login but , when I try to login it doesnt login only refresh the page without nothihng, so maybe I miss something or dont do like it should be . I use email address instead of username , and with ActiveForm it all work but when I try to make it custom there is some issue .

This is my login form that I want to make custom :

```
 <div class="login-message"> 
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <span class="">  Email  </span>
        <input value="<?php $model->email ?>" placeholder="Write your email address" type="text">
    </div>
    <div> 
        <span class=""> Password </span>
        <input value="<?php $model->password ?>" placeholder="Write your password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <div class="register">
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t("app", "Register"), ["/site/register"]) ?>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="forgot-pas">
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t("app", "Forgotten  password") . "?", ["/site/forgot"]) ?>
                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="login-button">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="_csrf" >
</form>
```

My action in SiteController for Login :

```
   public function actionLogin() {
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use ActiveForm?

Comment: you miss action in `<form method="post">` might be the reason

Comment: I set <form method="post"> same problem @Ripper

Comment: @marche I wanna learn alternative ways for making login form (without ActiveForm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing the `name` of every input. Because of this, when you try to load the post params using `$model->load()` will fail.

Usually `ActiveForm` generates these names in your inputs, however because you don't want to use it, you will have to generate them yourself:

```
<div class="login-message"> 
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <span class="">  Email  </span>
        <input name="LoginForm[email]" value="<?php $model->email ?>" placeholder="Write your email address" type="text">
    </div>
    <div> 
        <span class=""> Password </span>
        <input name="LoginForm[password]" value="<?php $model->password ?>" placeholder="Write your password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <div class="register">
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t("app", "Register"), ["/site/register"]) ?>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="forgot-pas">
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t("app", "Forgotten  password") . "?", ["/site/forgot"]) ?>
                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="login-button">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="_csrf" >
</form>
```

This way of naming your inputs follows the same way ActiveForm does it, because the `load()` method from your model is implemented to (by default) load attributes like `A[b]` where A is the model classname and b is the attribute name.

Comment: worked really thanks for the answer  and for the information !